# Relocation error

Tags: c, relocation

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define MAX 1000000

int dp[MAX];
int P[MAX], C[MAX], K[MAX], child[MAX][1000], index[MAX];
int mod = 1000000007;

void dfs(int i) {
    int j = 1;
    while (j <= index[i]) {
        dfs(child[i][j]);
        if ((C[child[i][j]] == C[i]) && (K[i] - K[child[i][j]] == 1))
            dp[i] = (dp[i] % mod + dp[child[i][j]] % mod) % mod;
        ++j;
    }
}

int main() {
    int T, N, X, i, j;
    scanf("%d", &T);
    while (T--) {
        scanf("%d%d", &N, &X);

        for (i = 0; i < N; ++i)
            index[i] = 0;

        for (i = 1; i < N; ++i) {
             scanf("%d", &P[i]);
             child[P[i]][++index[P[i]]] = i;
        }
        for (i = 0; i < N; ++i)
            scanf("%d", &C[i]);
        for (i = 0; i < N; ++i) {
            scanf("%d", &K[i]);
            if (K[i])
                dp[i] = 0;
            else
                dp[i] = 1;
        }
        dfs(0);
        for (i = 0; i < N; ++i)
            printf("%d\n", dp[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

When I compiled the above code, I got the following error:

```
In function `dfs':
(.text+0xa): relocation truncated to fit: R_X86_64_32S against symbol `index' defined in COMMON section in /tmp/cc0VMXET.o
(.text+0x3b): relocation truncated to fit: R_X86_64_32S against symbol `index' defined in COMMON section in /tmp/cc0VMXET.o
(.text+0x4f): relocation truncated to fit: R_X86_64_32S against symbol `C' defined in COMMON section in /tmp/cc0VMXET.o
(.text+0x56): relocation truncated to fit: R_X86_64_32S against symbol `C' defined in COMMON section in /tmp/cc0VMXET.o
(.text+0x60): relocation truncated to fit: R_X86_64_32S against symbol `K' defined in COMMON section in /tmp/cc0VMXET.o
(.text+0x67): relocation truncated to fit: R_X86_64_32S against symbol `K' defined in COMMON section in /tmp/cc0VMXET.o
(.text+0x74): relocation truncated to fit: R_X86_64_32S against symbol `dp' defined in COMMON section in /tmp/cc0VMXET.o
(.text+0x84): relocation truncated to fit: R_X86_64_32S against symbol `dp' defined in COMMON section in /tmp/cc0VMXET.o
(.text+0x97): relocation truncated to fit: R_X86_64_32S against symbol `dp' defined in COMMON section in /tmp/cc0VMXET.o
In function `main':
(.text.startup+0x6e): relocation truncated to fit: R_X86_64_32S against symbol `index' defined in COMMON section in /tmp/cc0VMXET.o
(.text.startup+0xba): additional relocation overflows omitted from the output
error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I know what this error is;how does it occur. I have searched for it in stackoverflow, but I can't understand how to correct it. Can someone please tell me how to correct my code?

Comment: how do you compile? What are the arguments? And on what platform? What compiler?

Comment: I think you have breached the capacity of an int with variable `mod`

Comment: @Md.RezwanulHaque Presumably the answer to that question is "without warnings", as usual.

Comment: @Md.RezwanulHaque: how is `int mod=1000000007;` out of range? 1 billion fits a 32 bit int. The value might be incorrect for the problem but it is not a range issue.

Answer (score 3):

You may to have hit a limit on the size of global variables defined in your program: the 2D array `child` alone has a size of 4000000000 bytes (4 billion bytes).

Either reduce the size of some of these global variables, or allocate them from the heap at start time with `calloc()`.

Try this version, where `child` is allocated from the heap:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define MAX 1000000

int dp[MAX], P[MAX], C[MAX], K[MAX], index[MAX];
int (*child)[1000];
int mod = 1000000007;

void dfs(int i) {
    int j = 1;
    while (j <= index[i]) {
        dfs(child[i][j]);
        if ((C[child[i][j]] == C[i]) && (K[i] - K[child[i][j]] == 1))
            dp[i] = (dp[i] % mod + dp[child[i][j]] % mod) % mod;
        ++j;
    }
}

int main(void) {
    int T, N, X, i;

    child = calloc(MAX, sizeof(*child));
    if (child == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "cannot allocate child array (%llu bytes)\n",
                (unsigned long long)MAX * sizeof(*child));
        return 1;
    }

    scanf("%d", &T);
    while (T--) {
        scanf("%d%d", &N, &X);

        for (i = 0; i < N; ++i)
            index[i] = 0;

        for (i = 1; i < N; ++i) {
            scanf("%d", &P[i]);
            child[P[i]][++index[P[i]]] = i;
        }
        for (i = 0; i < N; ++i)
            scanf("%d", &C[i]);
        for (i = 0; i < N; ++i) {
            scanf("%d", &K[i]);
            if (K[i])
                dp[i] = 0;
            else
                dp[i] = 1;
        }
        dfs(0);
        for (i = 0; i < N; ++i)
            printf("%d\n", dp[i]);
    }
    free(child);
    return 0;
}
```

Notes:

- You should also check if the values read from standard input are compatible with the allocated sizes (`N <= MAX` and `P[i] < 1000`).
- You can reduce `MAX` or `1000` if the allocation fails.
- `dp[i] = (dp[i] % mod + dp[child[i][j]] % mod) % mod;` could be simplified as `dp[i] = (dp[i] + dp[child[i][j]]) % mod;`

Comment: I tried to run your code .The previous problems have been managed correctly ;thanks to you.But,now it is giving NZEC which is segmentaion error.Please tell me how to correct it.

Comment: @ShanifAnsari: it is difficult to say without the test data

Answer (score 0):

The array `child` has `10^9` elements and each element is 4 Byte, so its size is almost 4GB. However, GCC has a limit on the data segment size and the default threshold is 2GB.

You have two ways to address this problem:

1. Reduce the size of the array `child`
2. Compile your program with the GCC option `-mcmodel=medium`.

References:

http://www.network-theory.co.uk/docs/gccintro/gccintro_65.html
https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.2.0/gcc/i386-and-x86_002d64-Options.html